# cannot update Craft CMS - composer errors

Tags: error, updates, updating, composer

I'm upgrading a site to 3.0.41.1 (not ready to go to 3.1) and when I do I get the following error. How do I resolve this?

```
composer update craftcms/cms
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.6.2, v2.5.0].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.6.2, v2.5.0].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.6.2, v2.5.0].
    - craftcms/cms 3.0.41.1 requires twig/twig ~2.6.2 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v2.6.2].
    - Installation request for craftcms/cms 3.0.41.1 -> satisfiable by craftcms/cms[3.0.41.1].
    - Installation request for twig/twig (locked at v2.5.0) -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v2.5.0].
```

in composer.json I have this

```
"craftcms/cms": "3.0.41.1",
```

All other plugins were successfully updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`composer update vendor/package` by design does not update the dependencies of vendor/package. Instead, use

```
composer require --update-with-dependencies craftcms/cms:3.0.41.1
```

Per the [docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require), `--update-with-dependencies` will

> Also update dependencies of the newly required packages, except those that are root requirements

That will update Craft to 3.0.41.1 and, because 3.0.41.1 has a new Twig requirement (~2.6.2, where 3.0.41 used ^2.5.0), it will update Twig as well.

Answer (score 1):

so this was weird.

I had the issue when I ran this composer command

```
composer update craftcms/cms
```

however when I ran

```
composer update
```

without the specific package all went well.

Answer (score 1):

Craft version 3.1.17.2 released -> https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG-v3.md#31172---2019-03-12

```
Craft now requires Twig ~2.6.2
```